# In Django, how do I construct a serializer that captures data in a join table?

Tags: python-3.x, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-3.2

I'm using Python 3.9 and Django 3.2.  I have a couple of models -- a Coop model, which has many Address models, linked through a join table (CoopAddressTags)

```
class Coop(models.Model):
    objects = CoopManager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False)
    addresses = models.ManyToManyField(Address, through='CoopAddressTags')
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False)
    web_site = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)
       self.save()  

class CoopAddressTags(models.Model):
    # Retain referencing coop & address, but set "is_public" relation to NULL
    coop = models.ForeignKey(Coop, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    is_public = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False)
```

I would like to create a serializer that can parse data POSTed from a front end app taht would then save these relationships,

```
class Coop(APIView):
    ...
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = CoopSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
```

but I'm having trouble figuring out how to incorporate the join table part of the equation.  Specifically I don't know how to capture the "is_public" field from the join table in the serializer and then save everything, since the join table needs both the Coop and Address models to exist.  I have this

```
class CoopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    addresses = AddressSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Coop
        fields = '__all__'

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super().to_representation(instance)
        rep['addresses'] = AddressSerializer(instance.addresses.all(), many=True).data
        return rep

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new `Snippet` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        return self.save_obj(validated_data=validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """
        Update and return an existing `Coop` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        return self.save_obj(instance=instance, validated_data=validated_data)

    def save_obj(self, validated_data, instance=None):
        addresses = validated_data.pop('addresses', {})
        if not instance:
            instance = super().create(validated_data)
        for address in addresses:
            serializer = AddressSerializer()
            addr = serializer.create_obj(validated_data=address)
            instance.addresses.add(addr)
        instance.name = validated_data.pop('name', None)
        instance.web_site = validated_data.pop('web_site', None)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

The problem is, when this saves, the "is_public" is always defaulted to true because I don't know how to submit it via JSON and capture it in the serializer.  Grateful for any advice here.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading about nested serializer -

Define your models as -

```
class Coop(models.Model):
    ---
    ---
```

and in **CoopAddressTags** Model add **related_name** for coop

```
class CoopAddressTags(models.Model):
    coop = models.ForeignKey(Coop, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="xyz")
    ---
    ---
```

and then -
first define you **CoopAddressTags_serializer** as usual and then **coop_serializer** as -

```
class CoopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    xyz = CoopAddressTags_serializer(many=True)
    # by default this is read only

    class Meta:
        model = Coop
        fields = ('id', 'xyz')
        # include all the field of coop model
```

till here, when you visit localhost:8000/coop, you will get all the objects of coopaddress linked to coop instance. Now to post write the create method of coop serializer as -

```
class coop_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ---
    ---

    def create(self, validated_data):
        xyz = validated_data.pop("xyz")
        #pass coop_address as list data along with coop data as xyz
        coop_object = Coop.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for each in xyz:
            CoopAddressTags.objects.create(coop=coop_object, **each)
        return coop_object
```

same way write the update method according to your requirements.